# How to get form data in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I found this neat post before asking this question (but doesn't solve my problem) :

I'm trying to update a record with ajax call using play framework as a backend.

Here is some data regarding my request :

```
Request URL:http://172.20.12.50:9000/updateName
Request Method:PUT

Form Data
name=&value=Testttt&pk=367
```

[image]

Here is how I try to test what I get on the server side :

```
Logger.info("PK IS " + request().getQueryString("pk"));
```

This is what I get in the log:

```
[info] application - PK IS null
```

How would I get these params from FormData? I got this data regarding my request from firebug

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The POST data is available in a controller with `request().body()`.

On the body, you can call `.asFormUrlEncoded()` to retrieve a `Map` of the data. You will find more information in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaBodyParsers).

For more complex use cases, you can use the [Form API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaForms) to define data constraints and validation and bind data directly to a specific class.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaForms

```
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

case class MyFormData(name: Option[String], value: String, pk: Long)

val myForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "name" -> optional(text),
        "value" -> text,
        "pk" -> number
    )(MyFormData.apply)(MyFormData.unapply)
)

myForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    formWithErrors => // binding failure, you retrieve the form containing errors,
    value => // binding success, you get the MyFormData value 
)
```

Obviously substitute `MyFormData` for something meaningful to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it for files:

```
val music = request.body.file("music").get
```

for body parts as an example:

```
var tracktitle = ""
        request.body.dataParts.get("tracktitle").get.foreach(value => tracktitle = value)
```